# Are there any rigid number fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

A field is rigid if it has no nontrivial automorphisms.  A number field is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.  My question is, are there any rigid number fields?

I’m pretty sure that if $K$ is a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then $K$ cannot be rigid.  But what about non-Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Did you try the case when $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279431/number-fields-with-only-trivial-field-automorphism) is some discussion that you might find relevant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every quadratic number field is Galois so the smallest possible counterexample is cubic. A cubic field is rigid iff it's not Galois: the simplest example is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: Is there a general characterization of rigid number fields?

Comment: @Keshav: it's a little indirect but you can work this out from the Galois correspondence. Embed a number field $K$ into its Galois closure $L$, which has some Galois group $G$. By the Galois correspondence $K$ is the fixed field of some subgroup $H$ of $G$. Now an extended version of the Galois correspondence tells you that the automorphism group of $K$ is the automorphism group of $G/H$ as a $G$-set, which is $N_G(H)/H$. So the necessary and sufficient condition is that $H$ is self-normalizing in $G$.

Comment: If $K$ is cubic and not Galois then $L$ is a Galois extension of degree $6$ with $G = S_3$ and $H = C_2$. The $G$-set $G/H$ corresponds to the natural action of $S_3$ on $3$ elements and has no automorphisms, hence neither does $K$. In the above example, when $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ then $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)$ and $H$ is generated by complex conjugation.

Comment: Also, what’s the simplest example of a non-rigid non-Galois number field?

Comment: @Keshav: you can take $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$. The Galois closure is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$ with Galois group $D_4$. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is a non-Galois subfield of index $2$ corresponding to the non-normal subgroup of order $2$ generated by a reflection (complex conjugation), and it has an automorphism $\sqrt[4]{2} \to - \sqrt[4]{2}$. The corresponding $G$-set is the natural action of $D_4$ on $4$ elements, and thinking of these elements as points in the plane around the origin, it has automorphism $x \mapsto -x$ (because it comes from a linear representation).

Comment: OK, thanks for all your help.

Comment: And to be a bit more explicit, the correspondence between subextensions $K$ of a Galois extension $L$ with Galois group $G$ and transitive $G$-sets sends a subextension to $\text{Hom}(K, L)$ (homs of extensions) with $G$ acting on $L$.